# It is possible to pass variables from a asp.net page to jsp page?

Tags: asp.net, jsp

I think GET METHOD is possible but I don't want all the sensitive information appears in the link, is it possible with POST method or session?

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt the query parameters from ASP.NET and then decrypt it on JSP end.

Comment: Any resource or example? Thanks.

Comment: And why cannot use POST method? Thanks.

Comment: I can transfer variable from html page to jsp page through POST method, so I don't understand why it would not work from asp.net front end POST method to jsp page.

Comment: A HTTP Post is a HTTP Post - so it shouldn't matter if you're using a GET or a POST. But the simplest is to use a GET. Start with a simple BASE64 codec if you want to protect sensitive information and move to better encryption algorithms depending upon how sensitive the data really is. Honestly though, I would use SOAP or REST services with Certificates if the data was so sensitive.

Comment: Can I use POST Method then?